# Post Form and redirect response

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

Hi I have code PHP and I want to convert this code into symfony controller

Code PHP

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Expires: 0");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";

echo "<form action=\"" . $url . "\" method=\"post\" name=\"form\" id=\"form\">";


echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"key1\" value=\"" . $code . "\">";


echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"key2\" value=\"$value\">";


echo ("</form>");

echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">";
echo "document.form.submit();";
echo "</script>";

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

This code must redirect  to another web site with the parametres posted is for authentification

this s my controller

```
class RedirectController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/redirect", name="redirect_root")
 */
public function redirectAction(Request $request)
{
     $data = array(
       'key1' => $code,
       'key2' => $value,
    );
    $url = 'http://login.php';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

I use the response of HttpFoundation but alway The params dons't passed to login

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse:

```
return new RedirectResponse('your_url');
```

or specific method (redirectToRoute('_route_name')):

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('your_route_name');
```

Comment: but the url to submit is in another server it is not root symfony.

Comment: Ok, then redirectToRoute is not your case. Use RedirectResponse('url'), where url is any url you need to be redirected. Or use retutn $this->redirect('url');